# replace existing product in cart when adding new but excluding specific products. Those specific product will be added and not gonna replaced

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

replace existing product in cart when adding new but excluding specific products. Those specific product will be added and not gonna replaced.
My code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart($cart_item_data) {
    
     
        
     $product_categories = array('mid-career-package-deal','advanced-career-package-deal');
    $excluded_ids = array(1105,1108);
    
    if(! in_array( $product_categories,$excluded_ids ) ) {
         WC()->cart->add_to_cart();;
    }
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    

    

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, your question contains several ambiguities: Which product should replace the existing product? you do not mention this in your question OR can only 1 product be in cart at a time? You also indicate that certain products should be excluded from this, on the basis of what? in your code this is based on the product category, although you again don't mention this in your question. So please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 
 'remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
 function remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, 
 $quantity ) 
 {
  $excluded_ids = array(1105, 1108);
  if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty()&& ! in_array( $product_id, $excluded_ids 
  ))
   WC()->cart->empty_cart();
  return $passed;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).